# Tracking paypal payments in a multi-seller marketplace setting

Tags: paypal, payment

I want to create a marketplace where users can list items and have buyers pay them directly through paypal. Is there a way to track these payments on our side so I can do things with the data (such as marking order as being completed)? I'm thinking that I could make the sellers set their paypal ipn url to my script but this might be a hassle. If it's not possible what kind of scheme would you suggest to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at PayPal's **Adaptive Payments** product.
[ https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/adaptive-payments ]

It allows you (as API caller) to set up a transaction between a buyer and a 3rd party seller.

Even though you are not a money receiver, you will still get a notification of the payment being completed via Instant Payment Notification (IPN).

As an extra, one of the nice features of Adaptive Payments, is that it give you the ability to do what's called a Chained Payment.

In a nutshell, it allows you to set up a transaction between a buyer and a seller **AND** it gives you the option to be a secondary receiver in the transaction.  What this does, is that it allows you to automatically take a commission from the seller, while remaining completely hidden from the buyer.

It's a really nice way of monetizing on your marketplace, with the added benefit that PayPal automates the whole thing for you. No extra programming required :)

Comment: Awesome! This looks perfect for me